# I'm trying to create a lists of lists, where my inner list is getting the same value for every index 'i'

Tags: angular, typescript, typeerror, nested-lists

This is for tasks and sub tasks creation in Angular 8 and TypeScript. I have tried using `Object()`, and 2D array. It is showing me two different errors:

1. Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
2. Cannot set property '0' of undefined

```js
tasks = [];
sub_tasks = [][];

task_to_sub_tasks(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tasks.length; i++) {
        this.sub_tasks[i].push(this.tasks[i]);
        var count = this.tasks[i].length;
        for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            this.sub_tasks[i][j] = x;
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a separate lists for tasks. I'm passing the sub-tasks name one by one on a *button click* after getting the input value for sub-task. I couldn't access the 2D array for `j = 0`, instead it throws:

```
Cannot set property '0' of undefined
```

Expected output is:
`sub_tasks[0][0]` should return the first sub-task created under `task[0]`

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, Can you share your sample data!

Comment: Hi I tried a different solution and it worked. `this.tasklists[this.index] = [];` Did this on the tasklist creation everytime ,and then pushed the subtasks using the Index of the task it belongs to. `this.tasklists[ind].push(subtaskname);`